# Order of custom pages in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using Inno Setup. I want to have two custom pages like:

```pascal
var
 PasswordEdit: TPasswordEdit;
 UserEdit: TEdit;
 Page: TWizardPage;
 Page2: TWizardPage;
...
 Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Page1', '');
 Page2 := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Page2', '');
```

But `Page2` is appearing before `Page`. Is this the proper way to create more custom pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want page 2 after page 1, then do:

```pascal
Page2 := CreateCustomPage(Page.ID, 'Page2', '');
```

[`CreateCustomPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustompage) returns a [`TWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TWizardPage). This has an `ID` property. This is what you can pass to the other functions.

---

So:

```pascal
var
 PasswordEdit: TPasswordEdit;
 UserEdit: TEdit;
 Page: TWizardPage;
 Page2: TWizardPage;
...
 Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Page1', '');
 Page2 := CreateCustomPage(Page.ID, 'Page2', '');
```